# WebApi: Put List<int> variable into the property of object type properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, type-conversion

I have a model property of `object` type to output from there values of any type, obviously. My task is put there `List<int>` value, but when I put it as is or, for example, as `list.Cast<object>()` I'm getting array of arrays like `[[1], [2], [255]]` in this model field after JSON serialization on controller output.

Important, that I can't change the property type. Any tips?

Here is the code of this property. `DocumentChildIds`, `BoolValue` etc are other properties in this model class:

```
public object ResolvedValue =>
            FieldType == CustomFieldType.Document ? DocumentChildIds :
            FieldType == CustomFieldType.Boolean ? BoolValue :
            FieldType == CustomFieldType.Date ? DateValue.HasValue ? DateValue.Value.ToShortDateString() : "" :
            FieldType == CustomFieldType.Integer ? IntValue :
            FieldType == CustomFieldType.DB_LOOKUP 
            || FieldType == CustomFieldType.LOOKUP
            || FieldType == CustomFieldType.MULTI_LOOKUP
            || FieldType == CustomFieldType.LOOKUP_TO_CLIENT ? (object) LookupId : StringValue; //by default all the rest types having string value
```

where `DocumentChildIds` having `List<int>` type and on input `{1,2,3}` I'm getting `[[1],[2],[3]]` in Json instead of `[1,2,3]`

Comment: Showing us some code, and some sample input and output, would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake. This property value gets through `Group by` after resolving where `ToList()` calling on it and becomes an array of array.

```
 var arrayValueFields = documentComposite
                .Where(i => ArrayValueResultTypes.Contains(i.FieldType))
                .GroupBy(i => i.FieldId)
                .Select(g => new DocumentItemFieldValueDto
                {
                    FieldId = g.Key,
                    FieldType = g.Select(i => i.FieldType).FirstOrDefault(),
                    FieldCaption = g.Select(i => i.FieldCaption).FirstOrDefault(),
                    FieldValue = g.Select(i => i.ResolvedValue).ToList()
                  ...
                 }
```

Do not repeat my mistake